# Can i set the width to 100%?

Tags: java, android, image, android-layout, textview

I use HTML to show image and text in the `TextView`.

In this case can i set width = 100%?

Here is my code:

```
public class ImageGetter implements Html.ImageGetter {

        @Override
        public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
            Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cs2);
            if (source.equals("img1")) {
                drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img1);
                drawable.setBounds(0, 0, width, 150);
            }

            return drawable;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean 100% if the original drawable. Have you tried:

```
drawable.copyBounds().width()
```